# How to create a function expression that returns an array?

Tags: arrays, return, function-expression

(The challenge reads like this)

Create a function expression named getNumberAr with no parameters

The getNumberAr function should return an array of 5 numbers

Call getNumberAr and store its result into a variable called numbers

So far I have created the function and not much else, looked through related post but could not put it together.

```
    function getNumberAr()
    {

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Think I got it !

```
const getNumberAr = function () {
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    }

    const numbers = getNumberAr();
```